# How do I make a link without <a href> show a mouse pointer instead of the highlight pointer?

Tags: pointers, mouse

```
<a id = "missionclick" class = "moreinfo"> More Information</a>
```

Currently shows only the highlight pointer when hovered over "more information", i'm trying to make it show the hand pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<a id="missionclick" class="moreinfo" style="cursor:pointer;">More Information</a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use cursor:hand, its not part of the standard and most browsers (FF, Safari, Chrome, IE9) won't support or understand it. Use cursor:pointer instead.

Answer (score 5):

The following CSS should apply a "pointer" cursor to all  tags without an `href` attribute:

```
a:not([href]) {
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "cursor" css property is what you are looking for.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can also try:

```
  <a id="missionclick" class="moreinfo" style="cursor:pointer;"> More Information</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line as well.

```
    <a href="#"> Your link </a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution. "#" declares a link as an anchor. If someone clicks on that <a> element, the browser will jump to the top of the actual site.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

`<div onClick="location.href='your link'">`